# ActiveRecord SQL execution time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

How can I get the SQL query execution time in rails?
I can see the time in logs, e.g.:

```
 Posting Load (10.8ms)  SELECT "postings".* FROM "postings" ORDER BY "postings"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
```

But how can I get that value (10.08) programmatically to use it further in my code?

Comment: What do you mean by 'get that number in my code?'

Comment: I need programmatically to know how fast my database inserts new record. In my example it shows 10.8 ms to execute the sql query (actually in my example it doesn't insert a value..). So I need to find a way to get that value and use further in my code.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use [ActiveSupport::Notifications](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Notifications.html) to retrieve the runtime of the SQL statements

You should be able to instrument `sql.active_record` to see how long the SQL call takes

```
ActiveSupport::Notifications.subscribe('sql.active_record') do |*args|
  event = ActiveSupport::Notifications::Event.new(*args)
  event.duration #how long it took to run the sql command
end
```

This code was not tested, so I can't guarantee it works, but it should

Answer (score 6):

try this out

```
time_consumed = Benchmark.measure { Post.limit(1) }
```

Comment: I tried but seems like this shows the time to execute a ruby in the block, including all activerecord and arel stuff... But I need the time for exactly sql query execution. I need to know how fast my database inserts new record, not ActiveRecord.