# SQL execution time in Rake tasks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rake

I've various rake tasks inside my rails app. One simple example is shown below.

```
desc "Simple rake task"
task :test_rake do |task|
    first_sql_query = FirstModel.find(10)
    SecondModel.create(:name => 'Test 101', :email => 'abc@def.co')
    final_query = SecondModel.find(900)
end
```

Now in the above rake task, we're making three database calls with each of them taking `x`, `y`, `z` seconds supposedly.

Is there any way to find out the total time spent on db operations(`x+y+z` secs) for a given rake task..??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ActiveRecord SQL execution time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18240624/activerecord-sql-execution-time)

Answer (score 2):

Use [`benchmark`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/Benchmark.html)

```
task :test_rake do |task|
    time = Benchmark.realtime {
        first_sql_query = FirstModel.find(10)
        SecondModel.create(:name => 'Test 101', :email => 'abc@def.co')
        final_query = SecondModel.find(900)
    }
    puts time
end
```

getting separate benchmarks:

```
puts Benchmark.measure { FirstModel.find(10) }
puts Benchmark.measure { SecondModel.create(:name => 'Test 101', :email => 'abc@def.co') }
puts Benchmark.measure { final_query = SecondModel.find(900) }
```

Comment: Does that for all task? How about each operation?

Comment: Tried this approach. This prints the total system time taken by a Ruby block. But a Ruby block contains statements apart from db queries. My question was to only find out the time taken by sql statements.

Comment: since these are fairly simple activerecord queries, I assume these bechmarks will give pretty accurate SQL load time

Answer (score 0):

@pattu Rails internally use `Benchmark` for execution time  check [say_with_time](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/migration.rb#L842-L849)
You can add the same function in a module and include in the rack task to find the execution time of SQL queries.

These Two functions are needed:

```
def say(message, subitem = false)
  puts "#{subitem ? "   ->" : "--"} #{message}"
end

def say_with_time(message = "")
    say(message)
    result = nil
    time = Benchmark.measure { result = yield }
    say "%.4fs" % time.real, :subitem
    say("#{result} rows", :subitem) if result.is_a?(Integer)
    result
  end
```

Use this in Your rake task as

```
desc "Simple rake task"
task :test_rake do |task|
  say_with_time do 
    first_sql_query = FirstModel.find(10)
    SecondModel.create(:name => 'Test 101', :email => 'abc@def.co')
    final_query = SecondModel.find(900)
   end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Query timing is included in the log file:

```
❯❯❯ rake db:migrate:status

database: ml_development

 Status   Migration ID    Migration Name
--------------------------------------------------
   up     20180612055823  ********** NO FILE **********
```

then:

```
❯❯❯ cat log/development.log
[DEBUG]    (0.4ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC
```

```

Comment: Sorry, didn't see that you want totals per rake task. You could actually parse the log file. But registering to notifications as suggested in the linked question is far cleaner.